# ChromeDriver DevTools support for Selenium 4 Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

Selenium 4 will support DevTools for Chrome. Is it planned to use these features on a selenium grid? And if so how would you initalize a ChromeDriver object.
What i am looking for is this kind of statement

`// this does not work
ChromeDriver driver = new Chromedriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

instead of RemoteWebDriver

`new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities)`

Comment: @RahulL nor ChromeDriver or ChromiumDriver gets a URL in the constructors. How would you init it, do you have an example?